# Ternary Relationship or (n-ary)

Tags: database-design, table, erd, database-diagrams

I'm trying to find the difference in terms of modeling a ternary relationship v/s a binary relationship in the following case. Any piece of advise would help me a lot.

1. Company has editors who are responsible for 1 or more papers.
2. An Author works with an editor on each paper, furthermore, he may be working in another paper with another editor.
3. Each Author may have none or more papers.

I managed to model this problem in two ways

First using a Ternary Relationship.
[image: Ternary Solving]

Second one is using two binary relationships and enforcing that each paper has 1 editor.
[image: Binary solving]

Is there going to be a difference in the tables that will follow any of this ways? I've tried to find any but failed to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference.

In the 1st design, an **author-paper combination** is related to one editor. So a paper can have many editors, as many as its authors.

In the 2nd design, a **paper** is related to one editor. And all its authors are related  - through the paper - to the same editor.