# Relational Database - How to handle many-to-many-to-many relation

Tags: sql-server, relational-theory

I am creating an ERD where i have the following strucutre:

- A tenant can have multiple users.
- A user can be in multiple tenants.
- A user has multiple permissions.

What is the best way to also have the permissions of a user scoped per tenant?
I want a user to have permission x,y,z in tenant A but have permission 1,2,3 in tenant B.

Any help on how to model this would be greatly appriciated!

EDIT:

Current part of the ERD

[image]

Comment: How far have you gotten in modeling this? If you show where you are (ideally, with some `CREATE TABLE` statements), that will make it much easier for folks to help you.

Comment: Firstly - let us not qualify any question as "best". That can't be measured and such a term is highly dependent on context as well as user. Since you seem to be new to relational modelling, perhaps it would be a good investment to educate yourself with a well-designed course on relational modelling. You don't "learn" to do that just by learning how to write SQL. As a shortcut, search "sql model a M:M relationship". If you get stuck, at least post the model (e.g. DDL) of what you have.

Comment: Added a screenshot of the current ERD part i have with the users. I know how M:M relations work and how to model it, but how do i model a relation between a user, tenant and permission? Cause i want to have permissions for a user per tenant.

Comment: You're looking for "ternary relationship", e.g. [like this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/144936/ternary-relationship-or-n-ary)

Comment: Thanks alot! This did help me out!

Answer (score 1):

You can model it like this:

- There is a Tenant, a User and a Permission which exist independently.
- A Tenant has many Users, and a User is in many Tenants, so there exists a many:many TenantUser relationship.
- That TenantUser relationship has many Permissions, and a Permission can be associated with many TenantUser relationships, so there exists a TenantUserPermission.

```
CREATE TABLE Tenant (
    TenantId int PRIMARY KEY,
    Name varchar(100) not null
);

CREATE TABLE [User] (
    UserId int PRIMARY KEY,
    Name varchar(100) not null
);

CREATE TABLE [Permission] (
    PermissionId int PRIMARY KEY,
    Name varchar(100) not null
);

CREATE TABLE TenantUser (
    TenantId int REFERENCES Tenant (TenantId),
    UserId int REFERENCES [User] (UserId),
    PRIMARY KEY (TenantId, UserId)
);

CREATE TABLE TenantUserPermission (
    TenantId int,
    UserId int,
    PermissionId int REFERENCES Permission (PermissionId),
    PRIMARY KEY (TenantId, UserId, PermissionId),
    FOREIGN KEY (TenantId, UserId) REFERENCES TenantUser (TenantId, UserId)
);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fffba369e1552d4beb3080f31b5925b6)

Note how `TenantUserPermission` does not reference the original `Tenant` and `User` tables, it references the `TenantUser` table, so there must exist a relationship for there to be permissions on it. You cannot assign permissions to a user before establishing that a user is part of a tenant.

Obviously you don't have to use surrogate keys, and you would normally name your constraints explicitly, but this gives a general overview.